# Play WS Recursive Get Requests for Pagination

Tags: scala, recursion, playframework, future

I'm trying to write a recursive function using Play WS to perform multiple get request to go through all pages that are given. Next page (with all query parameters) is given in the header "Link".

This function is only returning me 1 value, when I'd expect it to return several however, so I'm doing something wrong, but don't know enough about future recursion to understand whats going on.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

```scala
def getDnaProjectsIdsWithActivity(
                                   wsClient: StandaloneAhcWSClient,
                                   startTime: String,
                                   endTime: String,
                                   nextPage: String = ""
                                 ): Future[Seq[Project]] = {
  val request = nextPage match {
    case "" =>
      wsClient
        .url(baseUrl + projectResource)
        .addQueryStringParameters(
          "private_token" -> token,
          "visibility" -> "private",
          "archived" -> "false",
          "pagination" -> "keyset",
          "per_page" -> "1",
          "order_by" -> "id",
          "sort" -> "asc",
          "simple" -> "true",
          "last_activity_after" -> startTime,
          "last_activity_before" -> endTime,
          "owned" -> "true"
        )

    case page: String =>
      wsClient.url(page)
  }

  request
    .get()
    .flatMap { response =>
      val nextPage = response.header("Link")
      nextPage match {
        case None => Future { processProjectIdResponse(response) } // Process a json response to Seq[Project]
        case Some(value) => {
          val page = value.split("[<>]")(1)
          Future { processProjectIdResponse(response) }
          getDnaProjectsIdsWithActivity(wsClient, startTime, endTime, page)
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens to the `Future { ... }` in the `Some` case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you do not concatenate the current results with the results from the recursion. Try this instead:

```
request
  .get()
  .flatMap { response =>
    response.header("Link") match {
      case None => Future.successful(processProjectIdResponse(response)) // Process a json response to Seq[Project]
      case Some(value) => {
        val page = value.split("[<>]")(1)
        getDnaProjectsIdsWithActivity(wsClient, startTime, endTime, page).map { response1 =>
          processProjectIdResponse(response) ++ response1

        }
      }
    }
  }
```